# Thread Life inside Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, handler, timertask

I have an activity , inside the activity uses a timer task,change to Handler , if activity finishes is timer task or handler stop and terminate  or not?

Answer (score 0):

The TimerTask and Handlers are executed even after the Activity's `onStop()` method has been called. Any requests for `getBaseContext()` succeeds. Though, UI operations fail. Background operations continue.